# ElectronNet with ASP.NET Core and Angular issue with dependency

Tags: asp.net-core, electron, .net-5, electron.net

I am having issue with Electron.Net running the application. When application is run in regular mode (F5), everything works as expected. This is a simple backend with API together with SPA (Angular).

The issue happens once I run command `electronize start`. Upon running this command, the application **does start**, however API calls fail due to following issue:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostircs.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]:
> System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptiopn: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version 13.0.0.0'

Now, instead of getting exception from backend, it tries to route back to static files and serve `index.html` (which is even weirder).

This is what I don't quite understand as in my project I am referencing version 13.0.0.1. It seems to me, like `electronize start` does not identify correct version and always falls back to version X.0.0.0. I have downgraded my package to version 12.0.0.4, and yet, I got exactly the same exception that it could not find version **12.0.0.0**.

Do I need to update anything under my `electron.manifest.json` in order to make this work?

This is how my setup looks like:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("LocalHost");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                //spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        CreateMenu();
        BootstrapElectron();
    }
```

Comment: Try to delete CRM and reinstall from scratch：https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/using-newtonsoft-json-in-a-visual-studio-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late to help you but I came across the exact same symptoms and whilst I can't guarantee the cause was the same I can at least share what my solution was after hours of troubleshooting.

For some reason one of my class library projects that I was referencing from my web project wasn't including package dlls when building. Like yourself this wasn't an issue for me when running in "regular" mode only when running the "electronize start", if I had to guess it'd be related to the fact that running electronize start publishes a release version as single file output.

Anyway, the solution for me was to force my Nuget package dlls to be included with the binaries by adding

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

To the .csproj file of my aforementioned class library project.

Hope this helps!